# What hardware requirements does a SPV client have?

Tags: thin-clients, spv, bandwidth, storage-footprint

I read about SPVs [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Thin_Client_Security) that:

> [A SPV] client downloads a complete copy of the headers for all blocks in
> the entire block chain. This means that the download and storage
> requirements scale linearly with the amount of time since Bitcoin was
> invented.

but being new to Bitcoin, I don't know **how to quantify this** in terms of :

- **bandwidth**
- **storage**
- **ram**

requirements I need for running a SPV (on an embedded device).

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bandwidth - You need to receive an 80-byte header about every 10 minutes. In addition, if you want to spend, you will get SPV proofs that range about 500-1000 bytes per utxo. In other words, the bandwidth requirements are really tiny.

Storage - Each block header is 80 bytes, as of this writing, there are less than 430,000 blocks, so 80 * 430,000 = 35.4 MB. 100 MB should last you another 15 years.

RAM - The main usage of RAM is to do SHA256 and ECC signing/verification operations. A minimal CPU with not much RAM (512 MB) can do both without a problem.

Comment: Thanks. In terms of RAM/processing power, would you say a router with 32 MB flash and 300 MHz would do?

Comment: If you don't mind it being a little slow, that should be fine.